# (JS libraries) redux-thunk vs redux-saga

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I am currently learning both libraries. What are the criteria for choosing which one ist best for my type of application? Redux-thunk has three times more weekly Npm downloads right now. Is there any other big player I should know about?

Comment: This is very much opinion based, and based on the preferences and styles of individuals and teams.  Learn both, use both in projects, master both, then make your choice for any given project.  That being said, sagas4lyfe

Comment: @LarsOlt - it sounds like you are trying to optimize.............understand what thunk is trying to do - it's only 20 lines of code - get used to it; and then later on, if you wish, try saga.

Comment: If you are looking only for something for data fetching, then use thunks/redux-toolkit. If you have a complex app with lots of cross module data & action dependencies and other more complex async. flows use sagas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Redux Style Guide recommends thunks for most use cases](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-thunks-for-async-logic)

The reasoning behind it is simple: Thunks are very easy to use and most of the time "just enough".
At the same time, is is also recommended to use the official Redux Toolkit (which you best learn by following the official [Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)) and recently, Redux Toolkit is also shipping with an api caching solution called [RTK-Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) which - if you only need to handle api communication - might remove your need for hand-written sagas or thunks altogether.